# create bitmap with alpha from multiple drawables

Tags: java, android

I am drawing multiple resources  onto a bitmap via a canvas.  I would like the end result of the composite image to have a certain alpha.  Right now I'm setting paint's alpha to the level i want and then drawing each bitmap with that alpha, but i know this would create a composite image of a lot of different alphas.  Is there a way to apply an alpha to the entire composite image in performance friendly manner?

Answer (score 0):

You could draw all the drawables fully opaque (alpha = 255) to begin with, then draw over the entire destination Bitmap using [Porter-Duff](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) MULTIPLY mode with the right source alpha to change it all at one shot.